# Query para busca de relacionamentos no Oracle

Tags: oracle, query, desempenho

Tenho um programa para buscar dependencias de registros para proceder com exclusão de dados aqui na empresa. Temos suporte a alguns bancos mas no `Oracle` a query é processada com muita lentidão (cerca de 10 a 15 segundos para cada tabela em bancos de produção remotos).

Queries para consulta

### Tabelas pais

```
SELECT DISTINCT c_pk.table_name table_name, CAST(a.column_name AS   
         VARCHAR(100)) as MainColumnName, a.constraint_name, a.position,     
         a.table_name as r_table_name, c_pk.constraint_name r_pk,            
         CAST((SELECT ax.column_name FROM all_cons_columns ax                
         WHERE ax.owner = c_pk.owner                                         
               AND ax.constraint_name = c_pk.constraint_name                 
               AND ax.position = a.position) as VARCHAR(100)) as column_name 
    FROM all_cons_columns a                                                  
    INNER JOIN all_constraints c ON a.owner = c.owner                        
                          AND a.constraint_name = c.constraint_name          
    INNER JOIN all_constraints c_pk ON c.r_owner = c_pk.owner                
                             AND c.r_constraint_name = c_pk.constraint_name  

   WHERE c.constraint_type = ''R''                                           
     AND a.table_name = ''%s''                                               
  ORDER BY                                                                   
        table_name, constraint_name, position
```

### Tabelas filhas

```
 SELECT a.table_name, CAST(a.column_name AS VARCHAR(100)) as
       column_name, a.constraint_name, a.position,                           
       c_pk.table_name r_table_name,  c_pk.constraint_name r_pk,             
       CAST((SELECT ax.column_name FROM all_cons_columns ax                  
       WHERE ax.owner = c_pk.owner                                           
             AND ax.constraint_name = c_pk.constraint_name                   
             AND ax.position = a.position) as VARCHAR(100)) as MainColumnName
  FROM all_cons_columns a                                                    
  JOIN all_constraints c ON a.owner = c.owner                                
                        AND a.constraint_name = c.constraint_name            
  JOIN all_constraints c_pk ON c.r_owner = c_pk.owner                        
                           AND c.r_constraint_name = c_pk.constraint_name    
 WHERE c.constraint_type = ''R''                                             
   AND c_pk.table_name = ''%s''                                              
ORDER BY                                                                     
      table_name, constraint_name, position
```

Existe alguma maneira mais rápida de consultar estes dados?

Comment: As queries estão corretas, não há o que otimizar, creio. O problema pode estar no ambiente, SGA etc. As queries de produção neste BC são lentas ?

Comment: Como estão os índices?
O tempo de 10/15 segundos é para retorno ou para execução da query (Pode ser problema de rede)?

Comment: Por conta disto eu pensei e não achei , como coletar estatísticas nas tabelas de Metadados ?

Comment: @Motta o sistema em produção funciona normalmente, mesmo local a query não é muito rápida, mas o programa que temos que utiliza ela mapeia todas as referências de um registro, e quando temos que excluir um processo por exemplo ele faz elas para cerca de 50 ~ 100 tabelas

Comment: @FelipeFonseca como são tabelas e views do próprio Oracle, não sei se posso alterar os índices

Comment: Analisando vi que esta parte está contribuindo para a demora: `CAST((SELECT ax.column_name FROM all_cons_columns ax                  
       WHERE ax.owner = c_pk.owner                                           
             AND ax.constraint_name = c_pk.constraint_name                   
             AND ax.position = a.position) as VARCHAR(100)) as MainColumnName`

Comment: Caputo, já que as informações recuperadas são a respeito da estrutura estática das tabelas e não dos dados contidos nelas, não seria viável um sistema de *cache* dos valores retornados por essas queries?

Comment: @utluiz Hoje faço um cache por execução e não mantenho o cache entre execuções. Cada cliente tem sua equipe de DBA's interna e a maior parte dos clientes está em versões diferentes do sistema. Para cada tabela, só vou uma vez por execução, mas algumas vezes o registro tem tantas dependências que o processo chega a demorar mais de meia hora. Não utilizamos a ferramenta com frequencia, mas senti a necessidade de aumentar sua performance.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/appdev.121/e17602/d_stats.htm#i1055451 tente aplicar a coleta de estatíscas para o dicionário de metadados e veja se melhora.

Comment: Revisitando um post antigo meu lembrei disto , veja se coletar estatísticas do dicionário melhora algo http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_stats.htm#ARPLS68571

Comment: Obrigado @Motta, estou alocado para um outro projeto no momento. Vou tentar realizar o teste ainda essa semana!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente usar o hint PARALLEL e me diga se a query executa rápido:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96524/c20paral.htm

```
 SELECT
       /*+ PARALLEL(all_cons_columns 2) PARALLEL(all_constraints 2) */ 
       a.table_name, CAST(a.column_name AS VARCHAR(100)) as
       column_name, a.constraint_name, a.position,                           
       c_pk.table_name r_table_name,  c_pk.constraint_name r_pk,             
       CAST((SELECT ax.column_name FROM all_cons_columns ax                  
       WHERE ax.owner = c_pk.owner                                           
             AND ax.constraint_name = c_pk.constraint_name                   
             AND ax.position = a.position) as VARCHAR(100)) as MainColumnName
  FROM all_cons_columns a                                                    
  JOIN all_constraints c ON a.owner = c.owner AND a.constraint_name = c.constraint_name            
  JOIN all_constraints c_pk ON c.r_owner = c_pk.owner AND c.r_constraint_name = c_pk.constraint_name    
 WHERE c.constraint_type = ''R''                                             
   AND c_pk.table_name = ''%s''                                              
ORDER BY                                                                     
      table_name, constraint_name, position
```

Comment: Faço o teste agora no fim da tarde e já posto o resultado.

Comment: Desculpe pela demora. fiz vários testes e houve um ganho sim, mas apenas de 90 ~ 110 ms a cada 3 segundos. Mas obrigado se multiplicarmos por 100 ou mais já diminuiu alguma coisa

Comment: O valor 2 é a quantidade de CPUs vai brincando com os valores para ver se melhora ainda mais.