# Como coletar estatísticas nas tabelas de Metadados do Oracle ?

Tags: banco-de-dados, oracle

Coletar estatísticas de Tabelas de Users é simples, basta usar o dbms_utility.analyze_schema , mas tem como (e pode-se) fazer isto para as tabelas de Metadados do Oracle ?

Este [post](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/19139/query-para-busca-de-relacionamentos-no-oracle?noredirect=1#comment36088_19139), foi a origem desta dúvida.

Comment: Putz, ganhei a Tumbleweed (ótimo nome!!) por esta pergunta !!

Comment: Cara, não é a resposta que você está procurando, mas apenas gostaria de apontar que a partir do Oracle 10g a procedure `analyze_schema` não é mais recomendada. Você deve usar [DBMS_STATS.GATHER_SCHEMA_STATS](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/appdev.121/e17602/d_stats.htm#ARPLS68577) se quiser fazer isso na unha.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/appdev.121/e17602/d_stats.htm#i1055451 parece ser a resposta, vou testar depois.

Comment: Beleza, escrevi uma resposta para fins de registro (ainda que eu não ache que isso deva ajudar muito o OP da outra pergunta... A não ser que ele tenha desativado o *AutoTask* o Oracle faz um bom trabalho em manter as estatísticas em dia).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conforme meu comentário, em versões atuais do Oracle (>= 10g), as funções de análise de estatísticas para o otimizador são feitas com o pacote [DBMS_STATS](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/server.121/e15858/tgsql_stats.htm#TGSQL389), no geral porém essas estatísticas não são o problema; o Oracle possui vários *jobs* automáticos para coletar estatísticas regularmente (veja a [documentação sobre gestão de estatísticas para o otimizador](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/server.121/e15858/tgsql_stats.htm#TGSQL389)).

De qualquer maneira, você ainda pode disparar a análise de um *schema* manualmente com o *procedure* [`DBMS_STATS.GATHER_SCHEMA_STATS`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/appdev.121/e17602/d_stats.htm#ARPLS68577).

Em relação ao dicionário do sistema, existe ainda o *procedure* [`DBMS_STATS.GATHER_DICTIONARY_STATS`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/appdev.121/e17602/d_stats.htm#ARPLS68571).